# wildcard expansion using sql

Tags: mysql

I've a table named permissions.

```
CREATE TABLE `permissions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role_code` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `permission` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It has data such as

```
+----+--------------+----------------------+
| id |  role_code   |      permission      |
+----+--------------+----------------------+
|  1 | ADMIN        | app.*                |
|  2 | LOC_ADMIN    | app.location.*       |
|  3 | LOC_READER   | app.location.read    |
|  4 | LOC_APPROVER | app.location.approve |
|  2 | EMP_ADMIN    | app.employee.*       |
|  3 | EMP_READER   | app.employee.read    |
|  4 | EMP_APPROVER | app.employee.approve |
+----+--------------+----------------------+
```

I would like to query this table to get list of fine-grained permissions for a given role_code

For e.g., for role_code 'ADMIN' I would like to get

```
app.location.read
app.location.approve
app.employee.read
app.employee.approve
```

Is it possible to write a SQL query to achieve this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specification does raise some questions, but should be easily possible.

Since % is a wildcard character, and * is not, then you might want to use % as your marker.

```
+----+--------------+----------------------+
| id |  role_code   |      permission      |
+----+--------------+----------------------+
|  1 | ADMIN        | app.%                |
|  2 | LOC_ADMIN    | app.location.%       |
|  3 | LOC_READER   | app.location.read    |
|  4 | LOC_APPROVER | app.location.approve |
|  2 | EMP_ADMIN    | app.employee.%       |
|  3 | EMP_READER   | app.employee.read    |
|  4 | EMP_APPROVER | app.employee.approve |
+----+--------------+----------------------+
```

If so, then you could run code something like this:

```
SELECT a.role_code, b.permission
FROM permissionstable a
  JOIN permissionstable b on a.permission LIKE b.permission
       and RIGHT(b.permission,1) <> '%'
  ORDER BY b.permission
```

This does depend on my understanding of the permission strings.

Comment: Liked the idea of using natural sql wildcard!

Answer (score 1):

Without changing any of your data, this is what you need

## PROPOSED QUERY

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.permission FROM
(
    SELECT
    IF(LOCATE('.*',permission)=0,permission,
    LEFT(permission,LOCATE('.*',permission))) prefix
    FROM permissions WHERE role_code='ADMIN'
) A INNER JOIN permissions B
ON A.prefix = LEFT(B.permission,LENGTH(A.prefix)) AND LOCATE('*',B.permission)=0;
```

## SAMPLE DATA

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS krishnakumarp;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE krishnakumarp;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> USE krishnakumarp;
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE `permissions` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `role_code` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    ->   `permission` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO permissions (role_code,permission) VALUES
    -> ('ADMIN'        ,'app.*'),
    -> ('LOC_ADMIN'    ,'app.location.*'),
    -> ('LOC_READER'   ,'app.location.read'),
    -> ('LOC_APPROVER' ,'app.location.approve'),
    -> ('EMP_ADMIN'    ,'app.employee.*'),
    -> ('EMP_READER'   ,'app.employee.read'),
    -> ('EMP_APPROVER' ,'app.employee.approve');
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM permissions;
+----+--------------+----------------------+
| id | role_code    | permission           |
+----+--------------+----------------------+
|  1 | ADMIN        | app.*                |
|  2 | LOC_ADMIN    | app.location.*       |
|  3 | LOC_READER   | app.location.read    |
|  4 | LOC_APPROVER | app.location.approve |
|  5 | EMP_ADMIN    | app.employee.*       |
|  6 | EMP_READER   | app.employee.read    |
|  7 | EMP_APPROVER | app.employee.approve |
+----+--------------+----------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## PROPOSED QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT B.permission FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT
    ->     IF(LOCATE('.*',permission)=0,permission,
    ->     LEFT(permission,LOCATE('.*',permission))) prefix
    ->     FROM permissions WHERE role_code='ADMIN'
    -> ) A INNER JOIN permissions B
    -> ON A.prefix = LEFT(B.permission,LENGTH(A.prefix)) AND LOCATE('*',B.permission)=0;
+----------------------+
| permission           |
+----------------------+
| app.location.read    |
| app.location.approve |
| app.employee.read    |
| app.employee.approve |
+----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Using `DISTINCT` is probably unnecessary. You get the same result without using `DISTINCT`.